# Confusion about countability

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$(0, 1)$ can be proved uncountable by using Cantor's diagonalization argument. It shows there are real numbers not in the list $(x_1, x_2...)$, where $x_n=0.a_{n1}a_{n2}...$, a decimal expansion of $x_n$. I think I do not quite understand the proof since I'm not very convinced by it and it's clearly a right proof. I feel it somehow not explicitly showed that there don't exist any bijection function from $(0,1)$ to $\mathbb{N}$. I feel the proof is showing that since every natural number  is already corresponding to a $x_n$, there are not place for anything else. And since both $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ are countable, then all the natural numbers are already corresponding to $\mathbb{Z}$, but we can still insert the rational numbers that are not integer to corresponding to some natural numbers.What's the difference here? Can someone help me clear my mind? Thank ahead.

Comment: The proof is definitely not direct. One assumes there is a bijection from $\mathbf{N}$ to $(0,1)$ and writes $x_n$ for the image of the natural number $n$ under this function. Then a contradiction is derived using decimal expansions of the numbers $x_n$, $n\geq 1$.

Comment: I think this exact same point of confusion has been covered in earlier posts about Canto's diagonalization argument. Did you search the site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a nutshell, Cantor's argument was to show there cannot be a surjection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $(0,1)$. E.g. no matter what map you give me, there is always some real number that your map from the naturals does not hit. However, for the naturals to the rationals there are many surjective and bijective maps from $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$.

In addition, cardinality is an equivalence relation e.g. if $|A| = |B|$ and $|B| = |C|$, we see $|A| = |C|$. By using this we see by Cantor's argument that there is no map from ANY countable set to $(0,1)$, which bisects to $\mathbb{R}$.

Here's the intuition of why there is at least one real number not in the range of any  map from $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow (0,1)$.

Assume $(0,1)$ is countable, then we can list every element out, which is the hallmark of countable sets. E.g. for every $x \in (0,1)$ there is some $n$ such that $x=$ $x_n = 0.k_{1}k_{2}k_3.....$.

Now on our "$n^{th}$" digit of $x_n$ set $m_n = k_n + 1$ (with $9+1$ being sent to $0$). Then consider $\gamma = 0.m_1m_2m_3...m_n....$, clearly $\gamma$ is a real number. At the same time $\gamma$ is different from every $x_n$ because it differs by every $x_n$ by at least one digit. Therefore, $\gamma$ is not in $(0,1)$ as we assumed every $x \in (0,1)$, we can write out as $x_n$ for some $n$, but we showed $
\gamma$ is not on that list! But it clearly is also in $(0,1)$. Hence, we found a real number on $(0,1)$ that is not in our list, so we see no matter for what mapping we give, we cannot have a surjection from $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow (0,1)$. Therefore, it cannot be a bijection. Then by the equivalence class as $|(0,1)| = |\mathbb{R}|$, we see the result follows.

Comment: Thanks, but I still didn't quite understand how Cantor's argument shows there cannot be a surjection from N to (0, 1). I know how the proof goes, but not know how the process in the proof proved there cannot be such a surjection.

Comment: It's somehow seems to me that it denied one kind of mapping not all kinds of mapping from N to (0, 1). Where I am wrong?

Comment: Well, I guess another way of looking at this proof is that no matter what countable subset of $(0,1)$ that you give me, I can always find a number not in your countable subset (in particular the $\gamma$). Therefore, $(0,1)$ is not countable; otherwise, there would be a countable subset that contained the entire interval.